# Building settlements over the sea

Tags: catan, catan-seafarers

I know that in basic version of SoC each settlement must be at least two roads away from any other settlement. In Seafarers expansions you can build ships, so my question is - does this 'roads rule' also applies to ships? I haven't found anything about this in instruction for expansion.

In other words, can you build two settlements like this:

`O` is the settlement, `-` is the ship

[image]

Comment: Would be a sweet pair of settlements, though, with a #2 brick and a desert.

Comment: It's just an example! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty obviously NO.

Page 2 of the rules  -

> Except where noted below, Catan: Seafarers uses the same
>   rules as The Settlers of Catan

On page 4

> Shipping routes act as roads across water (or along the
>   coast). You build and place ships in much the same way as
>   roads

AND it specifically states

> If your shipping route reaches a coastline, you can then
>   build a new settlement on that coast, even if it is a new island.
>   Of course, you must still obey the “distance rule” from basic
>   Settlers, even if you are building on a new island.

So ships are 'water' roads and you still need two hex sides between settlements/cities

Comment: Absolutely correct here. Not that you'd want to build on the single corner of a desert anyway :)

Comment: This was just an example :)